# TI LM25118 buck boost, variable power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck-boost

For a part of my next project I'm required to make a variable power supply module. I have never designed a power supply and I would like to make my life as easy as possible. Thats why I would use [LM25118](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm25118.pdf) buck boost controller. The datasheet is a bit confuseing for me.

The input voltage varies from 3 to 6 volts (can deliver 4A). The output voltage needed is between 2 and 12 volts. The output voltage would be regulated with a potentiometer. I would like to look at the worst possible scenario when I have 3 volts at the input.

1. What voltage do I have to set to still get 1A at the output, while there is a 3 V input?
2. Is there a better solution? Like a controller from another manufacturer something else. I would need at least 1A at 5V out, 1A at 9V out would be great! (with 3V in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing technically stopping you from drawing 1A from this supply if your source is able to source that much *power*, and you take efficiency into account, and of course if you designed the inductor, switch and smoothing capacitors accordingly (which you can do by using TI's own *supply designer tool* on their website, so I assume you did that and will choose proper components by simply following its design).

So, the max input power is 3V · 4A = 12W. Your max output power is 12 V · 1A = 12 W. That can't work *with any supply, doesn't matter which* because there's no such thing as a 100% efficient power supply.

So, get a beefier input, or reduce your output requirements.

Note that it's not easy to operate a buck-boost supply at \$V_\text{in}\approx V_\text{out}\$; if that is among your requirements, more involved architectures like Cuk or SEPIC might be better suited.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me a lot. I did try TI's WEBENCH but when I putt in desired 1A at any voltage range i get these two comments:
"Cant find suitable FET for the design. Try reducing load current"
and
"Circuit calculator can't create design"